# Getting clicks to "fall through" a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, click, panel

I have a panel on a form that is placed under a control. I am going to use that panel to draw a gradient from black to transparent to simulate a shadow being cast from the control. However, there will be other controls underneath the panel, and the panel will catch clicks that are meant for the panels beneath it.

How can I get clicks to "fall through" the panel and go to the panel beneath it? I would prefer not to override the entire message proc. I am also open to other suggestions on how to do shadows.

Comment: can the panel be put in the background (i.e. at the bottom of all the controls?

Comment: @soandos No, it must appear directly under the menu bar. Then other controls also appear directly under the menu bar.

Comment: What you don't want to override is exactly what's needed to make that work.  Be careful what you ask for.

Comment: Or.. what? I'm just asking if there's an alternate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the clicks don't fall through like that (i.e. if you set up a click handler on the form and put a button on it, when you click the button only the button click handler gets triggered). What you can do is to cascade click events like this:

```
topPanel_OnClick() { bottomPanel_OnClick(topPanel, EventArgs.Empty); }
```

Obviously adds noise but it is way better than having a 'falling' behavior for clicks which would trigger a series of events.

Comment: That's the way you don't want to approach this.  Overriding `WM_NCHITTEST` to return `HTTRANSPARENT` is much cleaner than separately handling mouse down, mouse up, mouse move, mouse click, mouse doubleclick, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you could set `IsHitTestVisible` to false to accomplish what you want, but with winforms each control has its own window so you have to bubble events yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this titbit - I was trying to find if there was a way to do it in WPF and was about to ask my own question, then I saw this.